# jQuery add class to radio box not removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use jQuery to add a class to a radio box if it is selected.
That works fine, but it does not removed the class when selecting another radio box.

What am I missing?

```js
jQuery(".checkbox-radio").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        $(this).closest(".radio-inline").addClass("selected");
    else
        $(this).closest(".radio-inline").removeClass("selected");
});
```

```html
<label class="radio-inline conf-option-1">
    <input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[1]" value="1" checked="checked" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
    <i class="icon-addon"></i>
    <span class="addon-qty"></span>
    <span class="addon-text">Text</span>
    <span class="addon-price"> Text </span>
</label>

<label class="radio-inline conf-option-2">
    <input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[2]" value="2" checked="checked" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
    <i class="icon-addon"></i>
    <span class="addon-qty"></span>
    <span class="addon-text">Text</span>
    <span class="addon-price"> Text </span>
</label>

<label class="radio-inline conf-option-3">
    <input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[3]" value="3" checked="checked" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
    <i class="icon-addon"></i>
    <span class="addon-qty"></span>
    <span class="addon-text">Text</span>
    <span class="addon-price"> Text </span>
</label>
```

Comment: can u give a fiddle for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `selected` class from all `.radio-inline` and then add/remove `selected` as per condition as shown below.

```
<script>
jQuery(".checkbox-radio").change(function() {
  $(".radio-inline").removeClass("selected"); //add this
  if ($(this).is(':checked')){
    $(this).closest(".radio-inline").addClass("selected");
  }
  else
    $(this).closest(".radio-inline").removeClass("selected");
});
</script>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8vbgmura/1/)

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
The name attribute should  be the same for all your check-boxes
See here:
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8vbgmura/)

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but that does also not remove the class when switching to another radio button.

Comment: You do not need class in order to now what checkbox is selected you can use: attr.('checked')

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(".checkbox-radio").on('click',function() {
if ($(this).is(':checked'))
$(this).closest(".radio-inline").addClass("selected");
else
$(this).closest(".radio-inline").removeClass("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
$(".radio-inline").click(function() {

    $(".radio-inline").find("input").removeClass("selected");

    if ($(this).find("input").is(':checked')){      
        $(this).find("input").addClass("selected");
    }

});
```