# jQuery add class to selected radio buttons with specific label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently use jQuery to add/remove a class when a radio button is selected.
The problem is that it checks all radio buttons, so it only adds css to 1 radio button.

But in my HTML I use a row of 3 or 5 columns, where the class may only be added to 1 of the 3/5 columns.
But it should be also allowed in the next row, to add a class to 1 radio button if checked.

How can I achieve that?

jQuery:

```
<script>
jQuery(".checkbox-radio").change(function() {
  $(".option").removeClass("selected");
  if ($(this).is(':checked')){
    $(this).closest(".option").addClass("selected");
  }
  else
    $(this).closest(".option").removeClass("selected");
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-5"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[5]" value="21" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
        <span class="addon-text">Text</span>
        <span class="addon-price">Text</span>
        </label>
      </span>

<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-5"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[5]" value="22" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
        <span class="addon-text">Text</span>
        <span class="addon-price">Text</span>
        </label>
      </span>

<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-5"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[5]" value="23" checked="checked" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
        <span class="addon-text"> Text </span>
        <span class="addon-price">Text</span>
        </label>
      </span>



<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-1"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[1]" value="17" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
        <span class="addon-text"> Text </span>
        <span class="addon-price">Text</span>
        </label>
      </span>
<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-1"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[1]" value="1" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
        <span class="addon-text"> Text </span>
        <span class="addon-price"> Text </span>
        </label>
      </span>
<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-1"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[1]" value="2" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
        <span class="addon-text"> Text </span>
        <span class="addon-price"> Text </span>
        </label>
      </span>
<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-1"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[1]" value="3" checked="checked" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
        <span class="addon-text"> Text </span>
        <span class="addon-price"> Text </span>
        </label>
      </span>
<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-1"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[1]" value="4" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
        <span class="addon-text"> Text </span>
        <span class="addon-price"> Text </span>
        </label>
      </span>
```

Comment: is this not the same as the previous question?from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37672537/jquery-add-class-to-radio-box-not-removed) adding and removing class

Comment: @guradio No I forgot the problem with selecting all radio buttons. And I already closed that question.

Comment: I tested your code and it works, you can check it on https://jsfiddle.net/8f5gzgax/

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina Not exactly, see: https://jsfiddle.net/8f5gzgax/2/ Each row should have its own selected class. So that in each row there can be 1 red selected radio box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my understanding of your question is correct, the issue with your script is in the following line:

```
 $(".option").removeClass("selected");
```

On radio button selection, each "option" tag on the page (regardless of column number) will have the "selected" class removed. Instead, you'll want to try something like the following to limit the removal to the selected row, only (By finding the closest parent div/row of the selected checkbox):

```
jQuery(".checkbox-radio").change(function() {
  $(this).closest("div").find(".option").removeClass("selected");
  if ($(this).is(':checked')){
    $(this).closest(".option").addClass("selected");
  }
  else
    $(this).closest(".option").removeClass("selected");
});
```

Example: http://codepen.io/JasonGraham/pen/zBvwOK

This will then mean that each row can have one option tag with a "selected" class at any given time.

Comment: Thanks!! I only found 1 problem. The first radio in the row, is by default checked. So how can I add the class by default to that first row?

Comment: That should be pretty straightforward, just hard code the "selected" class onto the option that contains the radio button that is checked by default. I've updated the example: http://codepen.io/JasonGraham/pen/zBvwOK

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a bit. You need to check the `div`parent, not the `span`

```
jQuery("div").each(function() {
    var that = this;
    jQuery(".checkbox-radio", this).change(function() {
    $(".option", that).removeClass("selected");
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
      $(this).closest(".option").addClass("selected");
    }
    else
      $(this).closest(".option").removeClass("selected");
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8f5gzgax/3/

Comment: Thanks!! I only found 1 problem. The first radio in the row, is by default checked. So how can I add the class by default to that first row?